# Is there a way to make node titles longer?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am importing data which has some very long title fields in academic journals. Is there a way to lengthen the `title` property? Perhaps to 1000 characters?

Comment: FYI Google recommends you keep your titles short I would say to keep your titles less than 71 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple "I'm feeling lucky" on a google search for "drupal node title length" gives:

[Title Length](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_length)

> This module increases maximum length of node titles to 8000
>   characters.

Comment: what the hell... I searched for like 12 different variations of that same search and NEVER got that result. I even searched using the drupal.org search. *sigh* Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider having another field.  Title length is set in core and is restricted by a database field, I think it would be less work to have your own field and render it appropriately.

Comment: I upvoted this answer and the other one both, but I think this one would be the better way. Node titles are used in many places, including autocomplete results, and the 255 limit makes the `varchar` use smaller indexes, and light weight ajax responses. A large varchar doesn't make indexes larger than they the actual size of the indexed data (they are **var**chars), but expect some fragmentation a when updating them. Also, indexes can't be more than 767 bytes.

Comment: I've tried to do this before, then you have to try to hide the default field on the node edit forms (or auto node-title them) and it becomes a big pita. I'm just saying for my clients "more work" (fields) is rarely the answer.